# WPF binding user control with data in C# code

Tags: wpf, user-controls, binding

I've create user control like this:

```
public partial class View
    {
        public View()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static DependencyProperty NameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Name", typeof(string), typeof(TeaserView) );

        public string Name
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(NameProperty); }
            set { SetValue(NameProperty, value); }
        }

    }
```

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Controls.View"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="200" Width="164">
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          x:Name="Preview">

        <Label Height="28"  Content="{Binding ElementName=Preview, Path=Name}" Background="LightYellow" x:Name="name" VerticalAlignment="Top" ></Label>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and use it in Window1 simply in XAML:

```
<controls:View Height="200" Name="View1" Width="164" />
```

and I try set the Content in C# (Name property in this sample) but it does'n work, label's content is still empty. (All refereces, etc. are good) What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is wrong. You bind to Grid.Name property, which is "Preview", not to View.Name.

I really encourage you to go read from A to Z "[DataBinding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx)" on MSDN. It worth your time, trust me :). In fact whole "[Windows Presentation Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx)" section would be  worth your attention.

As for your code, the following will work:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication5.View"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Height="300"
             Width="300"
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
  <Grid>
    <Label Height="28"
           Content="{Binding Path=Name}"
           Background="LightYellow"
           VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

But are you sure you want to hide "Name" property from parents?

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the datacontext on the user control?  Try setting it to point to its own codebehind:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Copied your exact code and it works fine.

However, it's not doing what you're probably expecting it to do. You're setting the source of the binding to the `Grid` instance. Therefore, the `Name` property will yield "Preview". The Name property you've defined in your `UserControl` is ignored because there's already a `Name` property on `UserControl`.

Answer (score 0):

I've put the Name property just as sample. I'm trying to set Label Content in Window1.xaml.cs like:

```
View1.Name = "Casablanca";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following binding, it should work:

```
<Label Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:View}}, Path=Name}" />
```

You should also define a xmlns:local="whatever_path_you_have" on the top of the file.

I also suggest renaming "Name" DP to something else to avoid name collusion.